# CUDA compatibility

Tags: cuda

I would like to compute a c# function to test if my graphic card is enabled with CUDA. I know that the NVIDIA site responded by the knowledge of the model of the card and by looking at a list of enabled card at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus. But I want to do it with a program. Is there an existing function with CUDA Library which does the job or not? And if not, how to do it?

Thank you very for answers :)

Comment: If CUDA is not supported how could a program that needs CUDA help? It just won't run. But I doubt that this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know if CUDA is installed on a target system you should load the CUDA *driver* library dynamically as described in the .net blog here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/. With the driver library loaded you must first call [`cuInit`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__INITIALIZE.html#group__CUDA__INITIALIZE_1g0a2f1517e1bd8502c7194c3a8c134bc3) to initialize. If there's no CUDA runtime support this call will fail. If it succeeds you should enumerate devices using the device management [functions as documented](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__DEVICE.html#group__CUDA__DEVICE).